# Нужно ли удалять layout в деструкторе?

Tags: qt, layout

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText(tr("Text:"));

    line = new QLineEdit(this);
    output = new QPlainTextEdit(this);

    layoutHorizontal = new QHBoxLayout();
    layoutHorizontal->addWidget(label);
    layoutHorizontal->addWidget(line);

    layoutVertical = new QVBoxLayout();
    layoutVertical->addLayout(layoutHorizontal);
    layoutVertical->addWidget(output);

    setLayout(layoutVertical);
}
```

Как я понимаю layoutHorizontal и layoutVertical в иерархию объектов Qt не попадут и соответственно по цепочке удалены не будут? MainWindow здесь только для примера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы напрасно считаете, что эти объекты не попадут в иерархию.
`layoutHorizontal` становится "потомком" `layoutVertical` вот тут:

```
layoutVertical->addLayout(layoutHorizontal);
```

, а `layoutVertical` становится потомком `MainWindow` вот тут:

```
setLayout(layoutVertical);
```

Соответственно, явно уничтожать их в деструкторе `MainWindow` не нужно.

Comment: Немного добавлю. Удалять не нужно, но всё-таки можно. Ничего опасного от этого не произойдёт. Т.к. `QLayout` наследуется от `QObject`, то при удалении он отправит своему "родителю" сигнал `destroyed()`, по которому тот самостоятельно удалит этот layout из списка своих "детей". Повторно деструктор этого layout'а вызван не будет.

Comment: @aleks.andr, спасибо, честно говоря я этого не знал.